# How to Access SVG Paths Via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, dom, svg

**Issue:** I am experiencing the following error when uploaded to a server:"svgDoc is null" -- How can I prevent this?

Codepen: http://codepen.io/dada78/pen/65eeb7eeeefb6ed12a39c6012fd58196

**Description:**
I have an SVG (number.svg) that I am inserting into the DOM as follows:

```
<object id="number-svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="number.svg"></object>
```

I then followed these steps: http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/using-javascript-control-svg

Objective is to store all paths inside my SVG in order to then place them into an array in order to later animate the array items using a for loop.

**NOTE:**
I uploaded the test file to a server and it seems to work in Firefox, Safari **BUT NOT in Chrome**. In Firefox I do get the error "svgDoc is null" after refreshing, then it would work again, alternating with the error message on refresh.

Is it recommended to rather use inline SVG for manipulating SVG innerts with Javascript in order to work consistently?

Thanks!

Comment: You've told us what you tried, tell us what happened and how that differs from what you expected/wanted to happen.

Comment: Hi Robert, I added a codepen showing the issue. I don't understand why I can't animate the paths inside the svg object. I also tried using the SVG inline before with the same issue of animating each path using the random function (iconsIn)

Comment: The SVG and the codepen are on different domains. Cross-domain access is banned by your browser's security model.

Comment: Hm, but that's where codepen stores it's assets.